# Are there at least denumerably many distinct group operations on any denumerable set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working on a proof of the following statement: For any denumerable set $D$, there exist at least denumerably many distinct group operations on $D$. My argument is looking fairly messy, so I'm primarily wondering whether the result can be straightforwardly deduced.

Here, I'm considering two group operations $\ast_1$ and $\ast_2$ on $D$ to be $distinct$ if there exist $d_1,d_2\in D$ such that $d_1\ast_1 d_2\neq d_1\ast_2 d_2$.

Comment: I believe that Neumann constructed $2^{\aleph_0}$ distinct isomorphism classes of $2$-generator groups, but I am away and unable to find the details right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two distinct values of "distinct" that I can imagine you might mean, but unless I've misinterpreted your question, I think it's fairly straight-forward in either case.

If you mean "distinct up to isomorphism", then take the groups
$$C_{n}\times C_{2}^{\infty},\;\;n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}, n > 1$$
where $C_n$ is cyclic of order $n$.  No two of these are isomorphic, but all are denumerable (infinite).  Therefore, each is in bijection with your denumerable set (call it $X$).  Pick any bijection with $X$ and move the group structure over ("transport of structure").

The same thing works if you mean "set-theoretically" distinct.  But in this case, you can make the stronger claim that there are uncountably many (set-theoretically) distinct operations, since you can take any permutation of $X$ to create another (isomorphic) copy of any existing group structure on $X$.

Comment: Exhibiting countably many isomorphism classes of countably infinite groups is not the same as proving there are only countably many of them. Also your last argument needs a little more work, because a permutation on $X$ can preserve the multiplication table of a given group operation.

Comment: @whacka As I understood it, the question was to show there are *at least* countably many groups.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh yes you're right, nevermind that. Wonder why OP would ask such an easy question where there's a less trivial one just one word away...

Comment: Indeed, I meant "set-theoretically" distinct. Thanks.